# ¿Cómo hacer el COUNT de duplicados en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, count

Buen día, intento hacer una consulta en sql server , la consulta es mostrar la cantidad de empleados que se encuentran laborando en un departamento, y funciona pero en la columna de Cantidad empleados que es mayor a 0 me duplica el registro.
asi:

[image: SQL SERVER]

Este es el código de la consulta

```
SELECT 
D.idDepartamento, D.Nombre_del_Departamento, 
COALESCE (COUNT( E.IdPuesto),0) AS Cantidad_de_Empleados 
FROM Departamentos as D
INNER JOIN Puesto as P ON D.idDepartamento=P.idDepartamento 
LEFT JOIN Empleados as E ON E.IdPuesto=P.idPuesto
GROUP BY  D.idDepartamento,D.Nombre_del_Departamento,E.IdPuesto
```

Comment: Elimina E.IdPuesto de Grpoup by

Comment: Gracias Amigo, con eso me sirvio..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que quieres listar a todos los departamentos, tengan o no tengan empleados, voy a suponer que también quieres listar a los que no tienen ningún puesto definido, ya que tu consulta no los mostraría, voy a tomar otro enfoque que le da una vuelta de concepto:

Primero hacemos el *conteo* de registros, sin involucrar a la tabla de departamentos y, hasta después, hacemos un left-join de la tabla de departamentos con este conteo.

Mi solución preferida es usando CTE's:

```
with
Conteo as (
select Puesto.idDepartamento, count(idEmpleado) CantidadDeEmpleados
  from Puesto
       inner join Empleados on Empleados.idPuesto = Puesto.idPuesto
 group by Puesto.idDepartamento
)
select Departamentos.Nombre_del_Departamento, coalesce(Conteo.CantidadDeEmpleados, 0) CantidadDeEmpleados
  from Departamentos
       left join Conteo on Conteo.idDepartamento = Departamentos.idDepartamento
 order by Departamentos.Nombre_del_Departamento
```

Si observas, para contar, he cambiado a `inner join`, pues lo que realmente quiero contar son empleados, los puestos que no tengan ningún empleado no afectan dicho conteo.

La misma consulta se puede realizar con una tabla derivada de la siguiente manera:

```
select Departamentos.Nombre_del_Departamento, coalesce(Conteo.CantidadDeEmpleados, 0) CantidadDeEmpleados
  from Departamentos
       left join (select Puesto.idDepartamento, count(idEmpleado) CantidadDeEmpleados
                    from Puesto
                         inner join Empleados on Empleados.idPuesto = Puesto.idPuesto
                   group by Puesto.idDepartamento
                 ) AS Conteo on Conteo.idDepartamento = Departamentos.idDepartamento
 order by Departamentos.Nombre_del_Departamento
```

En mi opinión, esta consulta es un poco menos legible, pero da el mismo resultado y, conceptualmente, realiza la misma tarea.

Puedes lograr el mismo resultado con una consulta más parecida a la tuya, pero cambiando la forma de relacionar las tablas y de contar los registros, veamos primero el código:

```
select   Departamentos.Nombre_del_Departamento
       , coalesce(count(Empleados.IdEmpleado), 0) AS Cantidad_de_Empleados 
  from Departamentos
       left join Puesto 
                 inner join Empleados ON Empleados.IdPuesto = P.idPuesto
              on Departamentos.idDepartamento = Puesto.idDepartamento 
 group by Departamentos.Nombre_del_Departamento
```

Observa con atención la cláusula `from` y verás que estoy haciendo lo mismo que hice en los dos ejemplos anteriores. Hago un inner join de `Puesto` con `Empleados` y *después* hago un `left join` Entre `Departamentos` y este resultado.

Esta consulta, sin embargo, puede resultar difícil de entender/mantener para muchas personas y, si alguien más dará mantenimiento a tu software (y creeme, siempre lo hará alguien más más adelante), puedes ganarte un poco de odio por utilizarla.

Finalmente, para responder a tu pregunta, la consulta que usas muestra varias veces un departamento, porque has incluido el campo `e.idPuesto` en la cláusula `group by`, entonces, si un departamento tiene 7 puestos, va a aparecer 7 veces.

Como he dicho, no es el único problema de dicha consulta.

Comment: Por allá al final de la respuesta sale la frase clave que responde la pregunta del OP :) Yo habría comenzado por eso y luego le charlo sobre la buena nueva de la optimización

Comment: Consideré más importante darle una solución a su problema primero, para responder su pregunta al final, dado que la simple respuesta a su pregunta le dejaba en problemas (que aún no había visto). Por otro lado, en SOes, el término aceptado para referirse al _OP_ (en inglés Original Poster) es _AP_: Autor de la pregunta. :)